# How to load a picture into Google Colab for GitHub

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am writing a Google colab code + text and would like to export / save to GitHub. I struggle with pictures.

Option 1 is to use the picture load tool in the ribbon which does it but the image url gets unpredictably long which is very inconvenient for edits and writing.

I tried alternatively to load pictures to a folder nbextensions as suggested How can I open images in a Google Colaboratory notebook cell from uploaded png files?

```
%%html
<img src='/nbextensions/transformer-attention.jpg' />
```

which is an elegant way, but then when saving to GitHub, pictures which must be local disappear.

How to add pictures to the text in Google Colab in such a way that its practical for editing and it saves quickly to GitHub ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If shorter URLs solve your problem, then you can use https://bitly.com/ to shorten your image URLs.

Comment: thanks, a free equivalent?

Comment: You can try TinyURL.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can connect your Colab with your google drive,
so you'll have easy access to your images

And then maybe you can use something like [zappier](https://zapier.com/apps/github/integrations/google-drive) to connect your google drive to you GitHub

Comment: I prefer not to connect Google Drive to Github

Comment: Just want to add pictures to text should not be impossible